Swift package building in Xcode but not command line
I have a Swift package like:
// swift-tools-version: 5.10
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "nmbr-icu",
    products: [
        .library(name: "nmbr-icu", targets: ["nmbr-icu"])
    ],
    targets: [
        // Main NMBR target, contains 1 ObjC++ file (h + mm)
        .target(name: "nmbr-icu",
                dependencies: ["ICU"]),
        // Target to build the ICU framework, an xcframework for the ICU C++ code
        .binaryTarget(name: "ICU",
                      path: "./ICU.xcframework"),
        // Test target
        .testTarget(name: "nmbrTests", dependencies: ["nmbr-icu"])
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx20
)

The project structure looks like:

When I open this package (in Xcode - by double-clicking the Package.swift file) I can build (CMD+B) and test (CMD+U). However, running swift build returns an error saying that one of the header files in my xcframework cannot be found:
NMBRFormatter.mm:11:10: fatal error: 'unicode/unistr.h' file not found
#include <unicode/unistr.h>

What am I missing? The repo is open source here: https://github.com/kerrmarin/nmbr-icu

This is a partial answer.
The problem is because, when the target number-icu is built, it doesn't know where the header files are for the ICU library. I was able to give it a pointer in the right direction by adding to the target:
        .target(name: "nmbr-icu",
                dependencies: ["ICU"],
                cxxSettings: [.headerSearchPath("../../ICU.xcframework/ios-arm64/Headers")]),


This is similar to the -I switch when compiling C or C++
The reason I call this a partial solution is that the header search path is relative to the build directory for the target. You'll also notice the hard coded "ios-arm64" in the path. You'll need to figure out a way to include the correct header path for whatever architecture you are building. This shouldn't be hard, so it suggests there may be a different setting needed.
Although, I guess the header files shouldn't depend on the architecture, so maybe change your makefile to put them in a more generic location.

Thanks, this is useful. I'm wondering if there's something else I'm doing wrong because if I compare my package.swift to for example firebase, there is no mention of having to set the header search path
